# Python logging check if errors occured

Tags: python, logging, error-handling, stdout, stderr

I use

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

to activate logging of INFO and higher logging levels.

Is there a possibility to check at the end of my Python script if errors occured and exit the script with a correct return value (e.g. 0=successful, 1,2...=errors occured)?

I observed that my Python functions all work fine and I didn't catch any mistake but if I look into stdout there are some strings of logging beginning with "ERROR...". I want to recognize them and exit the script with "not successful".

Perhaps with checking of stderr (doesn't seem trivial to find errors in it...)?

Or with a handler and callback function and then mark there was an error (how to only know there were errors and no INFO, WARNING)?

Looking forward for some tips how to do that!

Thanks, Daniel

Searched in google for hours...

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage You to avoid "hacking" as long as possible and follow [PEP 20](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Logging module purpose is to create messages rather than tracking errors :)

You can simply add a custom class wrapping Your Logger and then just use it for logging **deferred** errors (e.g. `error_tracker.add(...)` doing the logging and collecting errors as a list underhood). Then whenever You'd like to check for any deferred errors it would be just a simple `len(error_tracker.errors)` check.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you allege "hacking"?
Thanks for the Zen of Python and of course explicit is better than implicit, but why should I program implicit? I always try explicit if possble and practible.

My current solution is:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logging.root.addFilter(on_log)
```

which calls on_log on every logging event and only allows to catch >= WARNINGs in a global flag otap_error (which is False after startup):

```
def on_log(record):
    global otap_error
    if record.levelno >= logging.WARNING:
        otap_error = True
    return
```

Would you agree with this solution?